# Can not remove axvspan from plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I am trying to delete an axvspan() function after clicking in the plot for the third time.

This is my code so far:

```
def shaded_region(self, event):     
    if event.button == 1 and ViewWidget.click == 0:
        ViewWidget.click +=1
        ViewWidget.xx1 = event.xdata
        self.cid2 = self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.mouseCoordsInMotion)

def mouseCoordsInMotion(self, event):
    X1 = ViewWidget.xx1
    X2 = event.xdata

    self.aspan = self.axes.axvspan(X1,X2, alpha = 0.3, color = "cyan")
    self.figure_canvas.draw_idle()

    self.cid3 = self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.selectedRegion)

def selectedRegion(self, event):

    ViewWidget.click += 1

    if event.button == 1 and ViewWidget.click == 2:
        print "Conectado a selectedRegion"
        self.figure_canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid1)
        self.figure_canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid2)

        ViewWidget.click = 3
        X1 = ViewWidget.xx1
        ViewWidget.xx2 = event.xdata
        X2 = ViewWidget.xx2

        self.aspan = self.axes.axvspan(X1,X2, alpha = 0.3, color = "cyan")
        return ViewWidget.xx1, ViewWidget.xx2, ViewWidget.click

    else:
        ViewWidget.click = 3
        self.figure_canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid3)

def erase_selection(self, event):

    if event.button == 1 and ViewWidget.click == 3:
        ViewWidget.click = 0
        self.aspan.remove()
        self.figure_canvas.draw_idle()
```

So, with the method `shaded_region` i start drawing from the coords of the mouse when i click once. Then i click a second time to stop drawing and when i want to erase what i have drawn with the third click, it does not work.

How can i accomplish this?. Hope you can help me.